# Replacing the whole line in a text file with vba

Tags: excel, vba, text-files

I have a text file that I would like a specific line to be replaced every time the macro is run. The beginning of the line starts with "POSTFIXFILENAME;", and usually has a date after it. I have the code below which replace that specific word. But I would like to replace the whole line instead of just the words as the date changes always. Thank you for the help.

```
            Dim objFSO
            Const ForReading = 1
            Const ForWriting = 2
            Dim objTS 'define a TextStream object
            Dim strContents As String
            Dim fileSpec As String
            
            'this open notepad and replaces the POSTFIXFILENAME with the required date
            fileSpec = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Traction Software\PDF Content Split SA\Content Split.pcs"
            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileSpec, ForReading)
            strContents = objTS.ReadAll

            strContents = Replace(strContents, "POSTFIXFILENAME; ", "POSTFIXFILENAME; " & Datefilename)
            objTS.Close
            
            Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileSpec, ForWriting)
            objTS.Write strContents
            objTS.Close
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, try this code:

```
Private Sub ReplaceTextLine()
    Dim objFSO As Object, objTS As Object, arrTxt, i As Long
    Dim strContents As String, fileSpec As String, sep As String
    Dim Datefilename As String
    
    Datefilename = "What you need here..." 'maybe Range("A2").value 'if I understood your comment
    sep = vbCrLf 'it can be changed with vbCr or VbLf, if different line separator
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    fileSpec = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Traction Software\PDF Content Split SA\Content Split.pcs"

    'all the text is read and transformen in an array, splitting it by vbCrLf (end of line):
    arrTxt = Split(objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileSpec, 1).ReadAll, sep) 'the obtained array
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrTxt) 'iterate between the array elements
        If InStr(arrTxt(i), "POSTFIXFILENAME;") > 0 Then   'if one element (line) containes the search string
            arrTxt(i) = "POSTFIXFILENAME; " & Datefilename 'it is replace whith what you need
        End If
    Next i
    'Now the array is joined (retransformed in string) on vbCrLf and written back:
    Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileSpec, 2)
        objTS.write Join(arrTxt, sep)
    objTS.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply, this deleted the line, however I want to replace it with  "POSTFIXFILENAME;" and a date from Range A2

Comment: @Mohamad Ballout: Upsss! I missed part of the point. I understood remove... I will adapt the code to do what I understood (only) now...

Comment: Thank you, the line now contains "POSTFIXFILENAME; 01-11-21", I would like to replace the whole line with "POSTFIXFILENAME;  and the new date here from Range A2". If this makes more sense. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @Mohamad Ballout: Please, test the updated code and send some feedback.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough, it worked flawlessly. I would love to understand a bit more of the code and what each item is doing. Will do some more research. Thank you again!

Comment: @Mohamad Ballout: Glad I could help! I will edit the answer and comment each line...

Comment: @Mohamad Ballout: Did it! If you do not understand something, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications...

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and clarification. Helped me aLOT